# Unable to deploy Rails application with Puma on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am unable to deploy my application to rails after almost three weeks of trying. I am using 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.5 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma) and Ruby 2.0.0.

**I have no error messages in the deployment stage:**
[image]

**When I visit the url I get no error message:**

[image]

**Here is my  /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log**

```
Using declarative_authorization (0.5.7) 
Using orm_adapter (0.5.0) 
Using warden (1.2.3) 
Using devise (3.2.4) 
Using exception_notification (4.0.1) 
Using exception_notification-rake (0.1.2) 
Using excon (0.37.0) 
Using multipart-post (2.0.0) 
Using faraday (0.9.0) 
Using httpclient (2.4.0) 
Using rack-oauth2 (1.0.8) 
Using fb_graph (2.7.15) 
Using hashie (2.1.2) 
Using heroku-api (0.3.18) 
Using launchy (2.4.2) 
Using netrc (0.7.7) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using rubyzip (1.1.6) 
Using heroku (3.9.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using httpauth (0.2.1) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.3) 
Using jquery-rails (3.1.1) 
Using jwt (0.1.13) 
Using libv8 (3.16.14.3) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.16) 
Using newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.1) 
Using omniauth (1.2.1) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.0) 
Using paper_trail (3.0.3) 
Using paperclip (4.1.1) 
Using puma (2.9.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.11.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2) 
Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3) 
Using rails_12factor (0.0.2) 
Using rdoc (4.1.1) 
Using ref (1.0.5) 
Using sass (3.2.19) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.3) 
Using sdoc (0.4.0) 
Using therubyracer (0.12.1) 
Using turbolinks (2.2.2) 
Using uglifier (2.5.1) 
Using will_paginate (3.0.7) 
Using will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1) 
Using youtube_search (0.1.9) 
Updating files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups test and development were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'bundle install --deployment --deployment succeeded'
bundle install --deployment --deployment succeeded
+ '[' -f Gemfile.lock ']'
+ echo 'encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions'
encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions
+ chown webapp:webapp Gemfile.lock
+ '[' '' = 1 ']'
+ true

2014-07-31 13:10:05,023 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:05,023 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh
2014-07-31 13:10:05,537 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: running 'bundle exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile'...
bundler: command not found: bundle
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
Rake task failed to run, skipping asset compilation.

2014-07-31 13:10:05,538 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:05,538 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh
2014-07-31 13:10:06,041 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: bundler: command not found: bundle
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
Rake task failed to run, skipping database migrations.

2014-07-31 13:10:06,041 [INFO] (18794 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:06,186 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/
2014-07-31 13:10:06,186 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01_flip.sh
2014-07-31 13:10:06,304 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
+ rm -rf /var/app/current.old
+ mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
+ mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
+ rm -rf /var/app/current.old
+ su -c 'mkdir -p /var/app/current/{tmp,public}' webapp

2014-07-31 13:10:06,305 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:06,305 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/02_restart_app_server.sh
2014-07-31 13:10:08,333 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: puma start/running, process 18871

2014-07-31 13:10:08,334 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:08,334 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/09clean.sh
2014-07-31 13:10:08,358 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: 
2014-07-31 13:10:08,359 [INFO] (18857 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-07-31 13:10:08,647 [INFO] (18879 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/
2014-07-31 13:10:08,647 [INFO] (18879 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] No files found to execute.
```

I have a database and the instance type is t1.micro.

Does anyone know what might be the issue I am encountering or how to go about fixing an errors? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As is written in the log:

> Executing script:
>   `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh`
>   2014-07-31 13:10:05,537 [INFO] (18794 MainThread)
>   [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info]
>   `Output from script: running 'bundle exec bundle exec rake
>   assets:precompile'...`
>
> ```
> bundler: command not found: bundle
> ```

The script: `opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh`

is trying to run `bundle exec bundle exec...` - something is not configure properly, check your configuration files.

Comment: Hi, ok I am thinking that the format of the commands in the .config file in my .ebextensions folder is incorrect (even though it deployed without an error). I can't post it here though, it is too long. I will have to research the proper formatting. The port is open too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problems with Rails and Puma. All EB Hooks run without error but the server does not respond to anything and neither throws an error in the /var/log/puma/puma.log

Still your scripts, probably overidden in .ebextensions/*.config are not correct by now.
You need to fix that one first.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am so lost in the process that i think I will be abandoning this attempt, if I come back to it I will be sure to respond. I understand your answer and the previous answer but I am having no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, while in the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, check monitoring for CPU usage when you load your URL.  If it hits anywhere near 100%, it means you need a higher tier instance because of the gems and dependencies that need to be installed.